# how to make thie non-pointer type property nullable in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, nullability

hi iam learning IOS development & for learning porpoises
i want to know how to make this property nullable in objc
(this Four @property)

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL Hood;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL smartclean;
@property (nonatomic) t_ShirtSize size;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger newsoftness;
```

because
when i use nullable i get this Error

```
@property (nullable,nonatomic) BOOL  Hood;

Nullability specifier 'nullable' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')
```

what is the Right way to make all 4 property nullable how can i do that (accept Null)

this is M file for The My app

```
-(instancetype _Nonnull) initWithSize:(t_ShirtSize)size
                         Hood: (BOOL)hoody {
    
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        Hood = hoody;
        _size = size;
    }
    
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This needs further context: Why do you need/want these fields to be nullable? What is being modelled here?

Comment: Objective C doesn't have optionals the way that Swift does. You can't make a value type null.  You would need to implement what Swift does under the covers by creating struct that has the wrapped value (a bool or Int) and a Boolean that indicates whether there is a value or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `nullable` annotation helps Swift understand whether a reference is optional or not when Objective-C code interfaces with Swift. It doesn't change the operation of Objective-C in any way.

`nil` can be assigned to a pointer in Objective-C even if it doesn't have a nullability annotation; that is just the nature of C pointers.

Scalar value types (Integers, bools etc) cannot be null in Objective-C, they always have a value since there is no pointer to their value. Their value is stored directly.

There is no direct Objective-C support for optional or nullable value types as there is in Swift

In Swift, an optional is actually a struct containing the wrapped value and a property that indicates whether the optional has a value or not.  The compiler hides this detail from you.

You could use [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber). This wraps scalar value types in an object. The object reference can be `nil` and so is `nullable`

```
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSNumber* Hood;
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSNumber* smartclean;
@property (nonatomic) t_ShirtSize size;
@property (nonatomic, nullable) NSNumber* newsoftness;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need a nullable `BOOL`, you can use `NSNumber` as a wrapper:

```
@property (nullable,nonatomic) NSNumber* Hood;
```

use `Hood = @YES; /* or @NO */` to assign a value, and `Hood.boolValue` to read the value again.

Note that, as others have said already, this is not a full replacement for Swift's optionals, and you have to take extra care to always use the correct data type - the compiler won't help you if you accidentally store a floating point value in your "nullable NSUInteger".

Answer (score 1):

A BOOL is a primitive, not an object. If you need an object, the usual thing is to wrap your BOOL in an NSNumber:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1415728-initwithbool?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1410865-boolvalue?language=objc

Now you have an NSNumber, so you have something that can be `nil` to indicate there is no object there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that nullability specifier anymore with BOOL properties, and perhaps also for the NSUInteger.

For BOOL, the reason why you don't need it is that it's by default `0` or `<nil>`.

Comment: but how can i fix this Code